# How to determine absolute path (if any) of a loaded Class?

Tags: java, reflection, jar, classloader, absolute-path

Is there a (compatible, if possible) way to determine the absolute path of a loaded Class?

Of course, this is not always possible (if you think of dynamically created classes), but
if the loaded Class is inside a jar how to get the absolute path for this jar?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

Fullcode:

```
    package org.life.java.so.questions;
   /**
     *
     * @author jigar
     */
    public class GetClassPath {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(GetClassPath.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());      
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

> /C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/argus/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/temp/build/classes/

Or

```
ClassLoader loader = GetClassPath.class.getClassLoader();
System.out.println(loader.getResource("org/life/java/so/questions/GetClassPath.class"));
```

Comment: Note that this may fail if the security manager will not let you know.  I believe this is the case in a Java WebStart sandbox.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
SomeClass.class.getResource("/" + SomeClass.class.getName() + ".class").toString();
```

If the class is loaded from jar the result should be something like:

```
jar://myjar.jar!path/to/SomeClass.class
```

Comment: Class name must be transformed to a path by something like this: `SomeClass.class.getName().replace('.', '/')`.`com.stackoverflow.Test` -> `com/stackoverflow/Test`